# Go Rest API on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm pretty new to go and I want to build a CRUD rest API on GAE without views just simple JSON Rest API.

There is allot of frameworks out there,
[go-http-routing-benchmark](https://github.com/julienschmidt/go-http-routing-benchmark).

But I'm not sure which one will be most suitable for GAE.

My main concern is how to handle a safe and secure session .

Comment: It's a matter of opinion on which router is best for the task. If you are new to Go, it's probably best to start with the standard library and then reach elsewhere if you need more.

Comment: I am new to go as well and developed this sample rest api in go after lot of research: https://github.com/rameshsunkara/go-rest-api-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can start with the Go standard library, and only utilize 3rd party libs if you reach a point when the standard library is not sufficient for you (which point you may never reach).

If your clients are not browsers (you said you don't want any views) but any other arbitrary HTTP clients, an HTTP session may not be what you want. An HTTP session is usually managed by storing a session ID in an HTTP cookie which is automatically sent by the browser along with each HTTP request, and at the server side this session ID is read and an associated, server side data structue is looked up by it.

A common solution is to use some kind of *secret information* referred to as a *key* or *API key*. The idea is that if you want to grant access to someone, you generate a *secret key* (e.g. a random text) at server side which you store in the database. You send this key to the client who has to attach this to every API request he makes. At server side in the beginning of each API request you can check if the provided API key is valid (this also identifies the caller) and act accordingly.

The API key can be sent in various ways by the clients, e.g. as a URL parameter (**strongly not recommended** for unsecure HTTP requests but is perfectly fine for HTTPS requests), as an HTTP header field or as part of the request data structure. It is really up to you how you expect it, usually depends on how the requests look like (e.g. if they don't include any data, it's better to put the KEY in a header or URL parameter; if the clients are expected to send other, complex data which can be in the form of JSON text, it can be convenient to also include the API key in the JSON data too).